# Naming Error when nesting df to scrape multiple pages using Rvest, Glue and Purrr

Tags: r, web-scraping, purrr, rvest

I'm trying to scrape football data per week 1-17 and by position (QB, RB, WR, TE) and I'm successful in creating a function to scrape the data but after I create a scaffold and try to add a third col to nest the weekly page per position results in I get the error at bottom:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(rvest) 
library(glue) 

url <- "https://fantasy.nfl.com/research/scoringleaders?position=1&sort=pts&statCategory=stats&statSeason=2019&statType=weekStats&statWeek=1"

scrape_19 <- function(week, position) {

Sys.sleep(3)  

cat(".")

url <- glue("https://fantasy.nfl.com/research/scoringleaders?position={position}&sort=pts&statCategory=stats&statSeason=2019&statType=weekStats&statWeek={week}")

read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>%  
  html_table(header = T) %>%
  simplify() %>% 
  first() %>% 
  setNames(paste0(colnames(.), as.character(.[1,]))) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  list()
    }

weeks <- 1:17
positions <- c("QB","RB","WR","TE") #only qb rb wr te as all columns 
match - will do k and dst separately later

scaffold <- tibble(week = weeks,
               position = list(positions)) %>% 
          tidyr::unnest()
scaffold

#here's where i get an error and get stuck
tbl_data <- scaffold %>% 
  mutate(data = purrr::map2(week, position, ~scrape_19(.x, .y)[[1]]))

Error in names(object) <- nm : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

I feel like I'm so close, yet so far.

Comment: I have a doubt.  In your code, the position is using values 'QB', 'RB' etc.  but in the `url` sshowed it is looking for numeric values `https://fantasy.nfl.com/research/scoringleaders?position=1&sort=pts&statCategory=stats&statSeason=2019&statType=weekStats&statWeek=1`

Comment: oh my goodness what a silly oversight. thank you so much that was it!

Comment: @akrun would you happen to know how the scaffold would need to be revised if I want to add another glue call in the url? I need to get the next page of data too for each position so I get all 50 instead of just first 25

Comment: Can you please inspect the page if there is javascript

Comment: I inspected and found "javascript" in a tag so I assume that means it is. Here is the url of that page too for your ref:  https://fantasy.nfl.com/research/scoringleaders?offset=1&position=1&sort=pts&statCategory=stats&statSeason=2019&statType=weekStats&statWeek=1

Comment: The second page of each position has "offset=26&" inserted after a particular "?" so I think the object page <- c("", "offset=26&") would be what i want to use in the scaffold as page one there is nothing in-between

Comment: @akrun forgot to tag you

Comment: Thanks.  I would check if by changing the values in the url individually,  you were able to extract the table before going into the loop because it may take lots of time and can end up with NAs or error

Comment: @akrun I tested it out and yes the function works fine by adding a third call to the function for {page}